# Regex_extract the next (and only the first) line after string

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

Using regex (on Ruby), how can I extract one line (only next line) after strings, like this

> **Title:**
>     this is the text I'd like to extract
>     Not this one
>     Neither this

I managed to extract the text using "Lookahead and Lookbehind" like this:

```
puts text.scan(/Title:[^;]*)Not this one/)
```

but the second part ("Not this one") is not always mentionned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?<=Title:\n)([^\n]+$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cF2pP7/1)

Check it please.

Comment: The () around the last part is optional, probably you wouldn't need.