# Extract text next line ignoring whitespaces

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, pdf

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166568/regex-extract-the-next-and-only-the-first-line-after-string), I asked how to match the next line after a string.

Sometimes, my PDF contains some white spaces that distort my result. For example, sometimes I have:

```
Title:  
this is the text I'd like to extract  
Not this one
Neither this  
(here my code works well)
```

sometimes, it's formatted like this:

```
Title:

this is the text I'd like to extract  
Not this one  
Neither this
```

Here is my regex in Ruby:

```
^(?<=Title:\n)([^\n]+$)
```

How can I make a regex extract the next line, provided that my matching text is cacharecters [sic] (text or numbers) and not white spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have read the entire file into the string:

```
text =
"Title:

this is the text I'd like to extract  
Not this one  
Neither this"
```

you could write:

```
r = /
    \b          # Match a word break
    Title:\s*\n # Match string
    \n*         # Match >= 0 newlines
    \K          # Forget everything matched so far
    [^\n]+      # Match as many characters as possible other than new lines
    /x          # Extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

text[r]
  #=> "this is the text I'd like to extract  "
```

Another way (among many) is:

```
lines = text.split(/\n+/)
  #=> ["Title:", "this is the text I'd like to extract  ",
  #    "Not this one  ", "Neither this"] 
lines[lines.index { |l| l.start_with?("Title:") } + 1]
  #=> "this is the text I'd like to extract  "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\S
```

not whitespace

```
\s
```

whitespace.

```
^(?<=Title:\n)([^\n\S]+$)
```

May not be entirely correct, but you should be able to get the gist of how you can use it. Essentially, you need to run an if else statement to determine how many extra new lines you need to cycle through before you get to the next character based on whether there is a matching space or not. What I've added to the code should read like this.

```
Start at a newline(\n) that does not have a white space(\S) before the matched string($).
```